# How to add multiple child nodes with the same tag to an existing node in an XML document

Tags: java, xml

I have a configuration file stored in XML with a structure like this:

```xml
.
<configuration>
.
.
.
<history></history>
.
.
</configuration>
.
```

I would like to end up with the following:

```xml
<configuration>
.
.
<history>
   <history_url>http://www.oldurl1.com</history_url>
   <history_url>http://www.oldurl2.com</history_url>
   <history_url>http://www.oldurl3.com</history_url>
</history>
.
.
</configuration>
```

I've looked at the Node interface which has the method `appendChild(Node newChild)`, but this states *"If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed."*

What is the easiest way to add multiple `<history_url>` nodes to the existing `<history_node>`?

The `Node` method `insertBefore` also states *"If the newChild is already in the tree, it is first removed"*. I've thought about creating a NodeList object, but I don't see any way to add a NodeList.

Comment: What library did you use?

Comment: I was looking at org.w3c.dom, I'd not progressed due to my misreading of the duplicate test. The solution below works now that I understand appendChild(Node newChild) properly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use appendChild.  The equivalence of a node is going to look at the object equality.  Here is example code for adding the multiple history_url child elements.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class NodeMultipleElementAdd {


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
          DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
          DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
          Document doc = dBuilder.newDocument();
          
          // root element
          Element rootElement = doc.createElement("configuration");
          doc.appendChild(rootElement);

          // history element
          Element history = doc.createElement("history");
          rootElement.appendChild(history);


          // history url element1
          Element historyUrl = doc.createElement("history_url");
          historyUrl.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("http://www.oldurl1.com"));
          history.appendChild(historyUrl);

          // history url element2
          Element historyUrl2 = doc.createElement("history_url");
          historyUrl2.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("http://www.oldurl2.com"));
          history.appendChild(historyUrl2);

          // history url element3
          Element historyUrl3 = doc.createElement("history_url");
          historyUrl3.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("http://www.oldurl3.com"));
          history.appendChild(historyUrl3);
          
          // write the content into xml file
          TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
          Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
          DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
          StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\temp\\history.xml"));
          transformer.transform(source, result);
          
          // Output to console for testing
          StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
          transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);
       } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks M. Rizzo, I see it now. I mistakenly assumed it would test equivalence on the tag name, rather than the object.